# Xamarin.Forms embedded image not showing

Tags: xamarin.forms

There are several posts here on stackoverflow that cover this, but none are the cause. I've tried several sources including the documentation and I can not get this to work.
I'm following a tutorial by mosh on Udemy and he's showing how to use an embedded resource file.
I am working with Visual Studio 2017.
I've added a folder in the HelloWorld folder called images and placed an image called background.jpg in it.

When you right click the image and set the Build Action to EmbeddedReesource you're supposed to get a Resource Id.  None is there, not even the box shows up. I'm thinking that's a new feature that was removed.

I found out the resource path is HelloWorld.images.background.jpg.

My xaml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="HelloWorld.ImagePage"
         BackgroundColor="Black">
   <ContentPage.Content>
      <Image x:Name="image" Aspect="AspectFill" />
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

Next, my c# code is like this:

```
    public ImagePage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

     image.Source =  ImageSource.FromResource("HelloWorld.images.background.jpg");
    }
```

And I've tried placing the image in the android project under Resources/Drawable, but doesn't that defeat the purpose?

Any help would be great.  Thanks ahead of time.

Here is my VS Solution Explorer:
[image: Solution Explorer]

Comment: can you show screenshot of your solution structure to make sure we understand it

Comment: "When you right click the image and set the Build Action to EmbeddedReesource you're supposed to get a Resource Id" - ONLY if you add it as resource in Android project and ONLY in Android project, not in PCL

Comment: "None is there, not even the box shows up." - That's probably why it doesn't work. You need to set it to EmbeddedResource in Properties.

Answer (score -2):

This way of embedding images is still supported. Check out [this page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Embedded_Images) in the documentation on how to do it. These are the basic steps:

- Set Build Action of the file to `EmbeddedResource`, you can do this in the properties of the file
- Refer to the image from your PCL with a dot delimited identifier. The filename is build up like this: *AssemblyName*.*Folder*.*ImageName*.*ext*

If your image is not in a folder, you can leave is out, if it is in multiple folders, add each one separated with a dot. An example could look like this:

```
var embeddedImage = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
embeddedImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("WorkingWithImages.beach.jpg");
```

Here the assembly (probably your project name for your PCL) is named 'WorkingWithImages' and the file is not in a folder, the file is named 'beach.jpg'. In the case of Android I think you should also mind that you do not put in hyphens or any other characters than numeric, alphabetic and underscores.

That being said, you also say:

> And I've tried placing the image in the android project under
>   Resources/Drawable, but doesn't that defeat the purpose?

I'm not entirely sure what you mean here, but I took it that you think it defeats the purpose of a multi-platform app from a single code-base. I must disagree with you there. Although I see how you could think that, working with images is something that is very platform specific. All platforms have a very different way of showing and scaling images and it would be nearly impossible to reconcile all that for Xamarin. Having the images in the PCL like you want to do now, will completely disable the whole scaling mechanism in place and suddenly *you* are responsible for making it look good on all kinds of devices, resolutions and form factors. That is why I always have the images resources per platform project.

Comment: Thank you for the link but I have seen this page and I've done exactly what it said, and I still cannot get the image to display in the Android project.  I don't care about the iOS part right now.  I'm just trying to get it to show up.
I set the Build Action to EmbeddedResource, and removed it from the folder.  I tried using ImageSource.FromResource("HelloWorld.background.jpg") and ImageSource.FromResource("background.jpg")
This was semi-simple when I was coding Xamarin Android but Xamarin.Forms is a weird animal.
I'm using a 1920x1080 image if that makes a difference, just to test with.

Comment: It's a long shot, but try a smaller image and/or check your build output. Android is kind of picky about image formats. If it is too big, it will complain to you only in the build output.

Comment: I downloaded the sample project and it worked.  Then I changed my program to look just like it.  It didn't work.
Then I noticed that the sample project was using an older version of Xamarin.Forms.
I am unable to upgrade it because it says:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error   Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.3.1' is not compatible with 'Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.247 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)'.

Things must have changed.  (I assume) because it's the only solution.

Comment: In the Docs this is still the way that is described: https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images what is not working for you?